# Angular Leaflet - GeoJson hidden on layer change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have a leaflet map with 2 layers

**First layer**

```
layers: {
    baselayers: {
        osm: {
            name: 'OpenStreetMap',
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            type: 'xyz',
            visible : false,
            layerParams: {
                showOnSelector: true
            }
        },
        vplan: {
            name: 'vplan',
            type: 'imageOverlay',
            url: 'img/map.png',
            visible : false,
            bounds: [[config.bottomLeftLat, config.bottomLeftLong], [config.topRightLat, config.topRightLong]],
            layerParams: {
                showOnSelector: true,
                noWrap: false,
                opacity : 0.6
            }
        },
    }
}
```

As you can see OSM is openstreetmap and the other on is PNG image.
Both layers are available in the layer selector - **OK**

Every second I make an Http request to retrieve geoJson data.

```
$scope.geojson = $http.get(...);
```

When landing on the page with the map, the geoJson is shown over the open street map - **OK**

My problem is that when switching to the other layer (PNG image) the geoJson is no more over the layer but behind. After setting the opacity to 0.6, I can see the geoJson behind.

How can I always put the geoJson **on top** of every layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Leaflet version 0.7.7 (or below), all your vector layers (typically from your GeoJSON data, except points) are grouped within a single SVG container.

That SVG container is a sibling of your Image Overlay (PNG image) in the [Overlay Pane](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-overlaypane). Whenever you use the Layers Control to show your Image Overlay, it is appended at the end of that pane, hence it appears **above** the SVG container, hence above all the vector layers from your GeoJSON data.

To force it behind the SVG container, you can use the [`bringToBack()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#imageoverlay-bringtoback) method.

To trigger that method when the Layer Control is used, you can add a listener on the map [`"baselayerchange"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-baselayerchange) event.

If you are using Leaflet 1.0, you can specify your own custom pane for your Image Overlay (or your vector layers) and specify they stacking order through `zIndex`.